# SwiftUI View keeps updating even when no longer shown

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I have simple View that is observing an object through the @ObservedObject property.
Something like this:

```swift
struct BrowserView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fs: FileStore

    var body: some View {
        List(fs.files) { file in
            NavigationLink(destination: BrowserView(fs: self.fs) {
                FileRow(item: file)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: loadFiles)
    }

    private func loadFiles() {
        fs.loadFiles()
    }
}
```

So what happens is that when a row is tapped I navigate to the next View which is still the same BrowserView using the same dataset (in the real code it's also passing other values as it's like a file browser andc the current path gets passed as an argument, too, but for the sake of the example it's really not relevant).

The problem is that when the next BrowserView appears, the dataset changes and those changes trigger an update of the previous View which is no longer visible and trying to update its UITableView is actually crashing the app.

Is there any way to tell a View to disable its bindings in onDisappear or something like that?
If not, what's the correct pattern when there's just a single model (storage) that is shared between different views?

**Update**

Here is the crashlog of what happens when the new view gets pushed onto the stack and the new data has been retrieved:

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x00000001b9a4643c in AG::Graph::import_attribute(AG::Subgraph*, AG::Graph&, AG::attribute_t, AGTypeID, AG::ClosureFunctionVV<void>, AG::ClosureFunctionFV<void, AG::ClosureFunctionVV<void> >) ()
#1  0x00000001b9a4c76c in AGGraphImportAttribute ()
#2  0x00000001c52b8280 in ViewGraph.import<A>(_:as:from:) ()
#3  0x00000001c53a9a20 in static StyleType.makeViewList<A>(view:style:inputs:) ()
#4  0x00000001c53a9200 in static ResolvedList._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#5  0x00000001c5203544 in closure #2 in static ModifiedContent<>._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#6  0x00000001c51e723c in specialized static MultiViewModifier._makeViewList(modifier:inputs:body:) ()
#7  0x00000001c51e8274 in protocol witness for static ViewModifier._makeViewList(modifier:inputs:body:) in conformance ButtonActionModifier ()
#8  0x00000001c52020d8 in static ModifiedContent<>._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#9  0x00000001c5203544 in closure #2 in static ModifiedContent<>._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#10 0x00000001c51e81dc in static ViewModifier<>._makeViewList(modifier:inputs:body:) ()
#11 0x00000001c52020d8 in static ModifiedContent<>._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#12 0x00000001c51795c0 in static View.makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#13 0x00000001c516b42c in static View._makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#14 0x00000001c542524c in AnyViewStorage.makeViewList(view:inputs:) ()
#15 0x00000001c54268a8 in closure #1 in AnyViewList.update(context:) ()
#16 0x00000001c5426648 in AnyViewList.update(context:) ()
#17 0x00000001c54289a0 in partial apply for protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update(_:graph:attribute:) in conformance AnyViewList ()
#18 0x00000001b9a3b88c in AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() ()
#19 0x00000001b9a3bd48 in AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) ()
#20 0x00000001b9a40cb0 in AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) ()
#21 0x00000001c52be0f4 in ViewGraph.runTransaction(in:) ()
#22 0x00000001c52bdea8 in closure #1 in ViewGraph.flushTransactions() ()
#23 0x00000001c52bdb20 in ViewGraph.flushTransactions() ()
#24 0x00000001c52bdc98 in closure #1 in closure #1 in ViewGraph.asyncTransaction<A>(_:mutation:style:) ()
#25 0x00000001c55759c0 in ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A>(body:) ()
#26 0x00000001c52bdc60 in closure #1 in ViewGraph.asyncTransaction<A>(_:mutation:style:) ()
#27 0x00000001c52d9a30 in thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () ()
#28 0x00000001c514ff64 in static NSRunLoop.flushObservers() ()
#29 0x00000001c514fed4 in closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver(_:) ()
#30 0x00000001c5150004 in @objc closure #1 in static NSRunLoop.addObserver(_:) ()
#31 0x000000018d7acee8 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#32 0x000000018d7a7b78 in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#33 0x000000018d7a8018 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#34 0x000000018d7a78f4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#35 0x0000000197bbe604 in GSEventRunModal ()
#36 0x000000019197b358 in UIApplicationMain ()
```

Comment: Are you sure both View need to access the same ObservableObject? Or can the secondView just create their own instance?

Comment: @davidev I'm using a single storage to hold all the state of the app, so it makes sense that all of the views access that same object (actually sub objects of that object most of the time). So the answer is that I cannot create a new instance.

Comment: Okay I understand. But what is your intention when changing data in the SecondView? Do you want the first one to update sometime or should it maintain it own data? What is the reason for the crash? A update of the first view shouldn't cause a crash? I understand you want to disconnect the observable object, but is sound for me like every new Browser View should maintain their own data. So a global object for every browser tab won't make any sense, will it? Still trying to understand

Comment: @davidev the alternative to accomplish what you suggest would be to provide the View just the portion of data that is needed. That would mean that I'd have to provide one element contained in a dictionary (the dictionary is like key=folder name, value=list of files) but then I have no idea how to publish just a slice of a dictionary, if at all possible. I could as well just bind to a function if that's possible

Comment: @davidev it is crashing because it's updating the List when the dataset changes and if the List is not attached to the view hierarchy it throws an exception. And it all happens within some proprietary functions so I have no control over any line of code that is causing that. It's damn hard to debug that behavior

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing shouldn't cause a crash... try this code:

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var files: [String] = ["red", "black", "blue", "yellow", "orange"]
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MainView(fs: Model())
        }
    }
}
struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fs: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(fs.files, id: \.self) {  file in
                NavigationLink(destination: MainView(fs: self.fs)) {
                    Text(file)
                }
            }.onAppear {
                self.fs.files.append("New Value")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's observing a model and updating in onAppear, and pushing the same view over and over just updates the list in the next screen as well as the first.

Comment: I agree with you that it shouldn't crash ideally, but what's happening is that it's crashing. I am adding the actual crash log in the original post for you to have a look at